# Periodically calling WriteableBitmap.Create() causing memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks, bitmap

I'm periodically receiving data (as `sbyte[]`, 1000 * 1000px, RGB) from a camera-like device, which I'd like to display in an WPF application. Therefor, I'm creating a `BitmapSource` from the data each time (at about 5 FPS) using a static class. Now it looks like the garbage collector is not taking care of the data I don't need any more, so my application uses more and more ram. I think I nailed the memory leek down to the following part:

```
void getImageTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_sensor == null) return;
    if (!IsImageGenerationEnabled) return;
    if (!_sensor.UpdateAllFrames()) return;

    ColorImage = ImageSourceGenerator.FromRawByte(_sensor.RawData, _sensor.Width, _sensor.Height);
}

public static class ImageSourceGenerator
{      
    public static ImageSource FromRawByte(sbyte[] colorData, int width, int height)
    {
        if (colorData == null) return null;
        return WriteableBitmap.Create(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null, colorData, width * 3) ;
    }
}
```

What I've tried so far to narrow the problem down:

- Commented `_sensor.UpdateAllFrames()` out, to make sure it's not the _sensor causing the leak. -> Still leaking
- Commented `ImageSourceGenerator.FromRawByte()` out -> Not leaking
- Feeding in static fake data into `ImageSourceGenerator.FromRawByte()` -> Still leaking
- Always returning `null` at `ImageSourceGenerator.FromRawByte()` -> Not leaking
- Slowing the FPS down, also slows down the leaking

What I've tried so far to get rid of the leak (ad did not fix it):

- Not having `ImageSourceGenerator` static and wrapping it into a `using()`-Block
- Calling `GC.Collect()` in the timer

How do I fix this memory leak?

Comment: Why not reuse a single WriteableBitmap and call WritePixels instead of Create?

Comment: Mhm. Well, that was easy - I just did not think of that. If you'd like to put your comment in an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of each time creating a new BitmapSource by `BitmapSource.Create`, you should reuse a single WriteableBitmap:

```
public static class ImageSourceGenerator
{
    private static WriteableBitmap bitmap;

    public static ImageSource FromRawByte(sbyte[] colorData, int width, int height)
    {
        if (colorData == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (bitmap == null || bitmap.PixelWidth != width || bitmap.PixelHeight != height)
        {
            bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgr24, null);
        }

        bitmap.WritePixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), colorData, width * 3, 0);

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```